# File owner after extract changes to irrelevant user in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

This is my topology:

```
My laptop ==> Ubuntu Desktop
| | |
User: root & saeed

My server ==> Ubuntu 20.04
| | |
Users: root & ubuntu (I deleted it as I explain below)
```

The steps:

1. I run `tar zvcf back.tar.gz .` in my laptop with user `saeed` and file is created.
2. I upload this file via SFTP to my server by using `root` user in path example `/home/test` which is not any user's home dir.
3. I extract `back.tar.gz` in `/home/test` but I see all of the files and directories' owner are `ubuntu:ubuntu`.
4. I deleted `ubuntu` user and tried the third step but got the same result.
5. I extracted `back.tar.gz` in my laptop in another path, but all files' owners are `saeed:saeed`.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When extracting as root, `tar` by default preserves the original owner ID. User `saeed` happens to have the same ID as `ubuntu` on the other computer (and it's probably `1000`). You can check IDs by running `id saeed`, or just `id` to check the current user.

If you don't want to preserve user ID, either don't extract as root or use the `--no-same-owner` option. Relevant fragment from the [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html):

```
       --no-same-owner
              Extract files as yourself (default for ordinary users).
```

The opposite can be achieved for regular users with `--same-owner`.

Related options `--owner` and `--owner-map` can be used when creating an archive:

```
       --owner=NAME[:UID]
              Force NAME as owner for added files.  If UID is not
              supplied, NAME can be either a user name or numeric UID.
              In this case the missing part (UID or name) will be
              inferred from the current host's user database.

              When used with --owner-map=FILE, affects only those files
              whose owner is not listed in FILE.

       --owner-map=FILE
              Read owner translation map from FILE.  Empty lines are
              ignored.  Comments are introduced with # sign and extend
              to the end of line.  Each non-empty line in FILE defines
              translation for a single UID.  It must consist of two
              fields, delimited by any amount of whitespace:

              OLDUSR NEWUSR[:NEWUID]

              OLDUSR is either a valid user name or a UID prefixed with
              +.  Unless NEWUID is supplied, NEWUSR must also be either
              a valid user name or a +UID.  Otherwise, both NEWUSR and
              NEWUID need not be listed in the system user database.

              As a result, each input file owned by OLDUSR will be
              stored in archive with owner name NEWUSR and UID NEWUID.
```

Comment: Thanks @KamilMaciorowski and @gronostaj for the answer and the comment. I got it:) Both `saeed` and `ubuntu` has UID 1000, and I got it why this happens which was a great question and barrier in my mind:)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I expected to be `root:root` because I ssh to my server as `root`, but that was unclear for me why owner changes to a user that has nothing to do with this upload and extract process. I'll use `--no-same-owner` the next time